# Microsoft Graph team creation error: "CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Creating teams via the Graph API *used to work fine* using this json:

```json
// POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams
{
    "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
    "displayName": "TeamName",
    "members": [
        {
            "roles": [
                "owner"
            ],
            "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('...')",
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember"
        }
    ]
}
```

but now I keep getting this error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NotFound",
        "message": "Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/emea/templates/api/team, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: NotFound, Response Headers: ...",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/emea/templates/api/team, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: NotFound, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: ..., ErrorMessage : {\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Error when calling Middle Tier. Message: ''. Error code: 'NotFound'. Status code: NotFound.\",\"errorCode\":\"Unknown\"}],\"operationId\":\"...\"}",
            "code": "ItemNotFound",
            "innerError": {},
            "date": "2021-11-05T15:49:22",
            "request-id": "...",
            "client-request-id": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing somthing wrong or is this a regression? If it is, I would very much appreciate a fix from Microsoft since I need the ability to create teams.

Comment: We have repro this issue. The user id whichever mentioned in user@odata.bind need to correct. If the user is not present of that id, then NotFound error come. Could you please check using another user id.?

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue is resolved with above solution or still you need any help?

Comment: You are correct, the error happens when the userId does not exist in the tenant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user id whichever mentioned in user@odata.bind need to correct. If the user is not present of that id, then `NotFound` error come.

Please check you are passing correct user id.